# QGIS systematically guesses wrong CRS

Tags: qgis

QGIS (1.7) systematically applies the wrong CRS when adding layers (or shapefiles from a given lot). They should be NAD83__MTM9 (EPSG:32189), as can be inferred from the prj-file, but the properties/general/options field show NAD27(CGQ77)/SCPQ_zone9. (EPSG:2015)

Granted from there, I can specify/apply the correct CRS and the layers will line up. But it is a drag to do, and redo again, for many shapefiles. Is there anyway to correct that behavior or a better approach?

**Update:** indeed corrected with the installation of 1.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a known bug in Qgis 1.7. Try the current version 1.8 and see if it persists. Other way would be to include .qpj files. They are created by qgis after saving, adding some more information than .prj does.

Comment: correct, try qgis 1.8, there have been changes in the crs detection mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out it is a documented bug. I'll get around to update to 1.8 and try it again.